# iPhone SDK: CustomControls as in C#

Tags: iphone, uiview, resize, subclass

I have a UIViewController. The UIViewController has a NIB with one outlet - a UIView, containing several buttons and labels. Imagine, it is something like a UIDatePicker.

In order to not be forced to copy and paste all the controlling code into a new environment, I was trying to encapsulate the UIView into a separate UIView subclass with an own NIB, sort of a C# CustomControl approach.

From a controlling (other) UIViewController I'm instantiating the view from the NIB

```
NSArray *nibObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyView" owner:self options:nil];
selectorView = (DateTimeSelectorView*)[nibObjects objectAtIndex:0];
```

selectorView is a property in the using UIViewController class. The problem: "initWithFrame" of my UIView is never called. My UIView is covering the whole space (320x480), whereas it should have a smaller size. How can I achive this? Furthermore the UIView seems to hide all other controls, instantiated from the UIViewController class.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

When a view is instantiated by the nib loader, initWithFrame: isn't called.  The nib loader calls initWithCoder:.  You should implement initWithCoder to perform any initialization, including setting the frame.

Comment: Thanks. Meanwhile I found the answer. It is not obvious. I will assemble a small "How To"

Answer (score 0):

So here is a "HowTo" for the question: How to embed a self-contained UIView into my UIViewController *with* NIB?

1) Say you have a UIView with a button and a textfield, making some login. You have the UI in a separate NIB called Login.xib. The functionality is in Login.m and Login.h, a subclass of UIView. The class name is "Login". Take care, that the class is set properly in Login.xib. Everything is fine.

2) Now you want to use this "out of the box" in a new app.

3) Drag the three files (Login.m, Login.h and Login.xib") into your new UIView based project

4) Add a property in your UIViewController class, pointing to your Login class (of course, include the Login.h first)

5) Open IB with Login.xib and set the file's owner to your current UIViewController class

6) Connect the main view of your Login.xib with the property defined in UIViewController (!! this is important !!)

7) Add the following to your viewDidLoad in UIViewController (supposed, the name of your property is "myLogin")

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Login" owner:self options:nil];
myLogin.frame = CGRectMake(0 ,100, 320, 200); // Optional, you may also use the initial bounds
[self.view addSubview:myLogin];
```

The view will appear where you let it appear. Other controls from your superview will be available too.

It took me several hours to find that out. There is here and there some scattered info, but I didn't find a complete "how to" for that simple task up to now.

Regards